# Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to have this section from the Jenkins UI into a Jenkinsfile instead?

[image: Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pollSCM trigger.

Eg: `triggers { pollSCM('H */4 * * 1-5') }`

Doc: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/